# Forcing bundle install --without to rewrite Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, docker

I am using `bundle package` to write gems to vendor/cache before building a docker image. I then run `RAILS_ENV=docker_env bundle install --local --without development test` in my Dockerfile to install the cached gems which runs without an issue. However when I try to `bundle exec ...` or anything to do with bundle it complains about missing gems but the gems it is complaining about are in the development and test groups which it shouldn't be trying to load.

They are specified in the Gemfile.lock, but my understanding is that running `bundle install --without development test` should remove them from the Gemfile.lock. I can manually delete them from the Gemfile.lock which fixes the problem but this is obviously not a  practical workaround.

I tried appending the --clean flag to the bundle install but this did not help. Any ideas on why the development/test gems are not being removed from Gemfile.lock?